# copying ViewController from another project causes NSScanner: nil string argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I copied a ViewController from another working project opened as separate Xcode window. And it showed no errors but at run time I'm getting

```
NSScanner: nil string argument
```

I put breakpoints and found out that occurs where I switch to the new ViewController(copied ViewContoller)..

```
GCHConnectViewController* gchConnectViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gchChoose"];
```

I checked many times and..

Storyboard ID is correct (i.e gchChoose) 
Use Storyboard Id checkbox is checked 
Custom class > class is correct (i.e GCHConnectViewController)

I've 7 ViewControllers copied from the other project, and they all cause the same error when I try to switch to them, but other ViewControllers (which were not copied) works fine when switching..

I been trying to figure out what's the problem for an hour now, but no luck. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you copying the view controllers file, or just the contents of the file? Check that the target membership of the file is correct.

Comment: That isn't enough information to help you.  View controllers are inherently related to the `NSScanner` class.  Are you using the `NSScanner` class in your code?

Comment: @DanielOrmeño yes, I did also copy ViewController's .h and .m files from the other project.. How do I check that? Target membership??

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning you project first of.

Also, check that all the outlets/actions are in proper place. Also, check that if in previous project the view controller had segue, delete those.

Comment: did you set any storyboard id? or any identifier related to tableview or such thing as view controller id? You would have to do the same.

Also make sure your segue identifiers are perfectly set

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your IBOuttes and IBActions are properly connected. and Twice check that you doesn't have multiple referencing outlets or actions for same event(Whether it is connected or not).

You can check it from connection inspector. so select every object of vew controller and check connection insperctor for each one by one.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: They all seems to be correct. Now I tried adding a new UIViewController (just a blank view no outlets or actions) . I can't even switch to it.. Actually I'm editing a project and adding a few new screens and I can switch to the ViewControllers which were already there but not new ones.